# The markup in the document following the root element must be well-informed

Tags: java, android, xml

Okay, so I am getting the error which was stated in the title. I have searched for people with similar problems but for some reason the answers given to them did not work for me.

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
              android:title="@string/action_settings"
              android:showAsAction="never" />
    </menu>
```

I get the error at line 9 which is where the menu opening tag is. Please help understand what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have a file that contains both layout code (`FrameLayout`) and menu code (`menu`)? Those are completely different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `FrameLayout` is your root tag, it needs to contain the rest of the document.  You seem to be closing it before starting the rest of the document.

It should likely look something like:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
              android:title="@string/action_settings"
              android:showAsAction="never" />
    </menu>
</FrameLayout>
```